# IDE for CodeIgniter running in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: php, ide, codeigniter, editor

I have search the existing question here, but haven't get the specific detail that I need, so I'm asking my own question.

I use Ubuntu Linux (current version 9.10) and use Eclipse Galileo PDT to develop web application using CodeIgniter. I can make the autocomplete worked for CodeIgniter's libraries and model using this comment in my controller file:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 *
 * @author donny
 * @property CI_Loader $load
 * @property CI_Input $input
 * @property CI_Output $output
 * @property CI_Email $email
 * @property CI_Form_validation $form_validation
 * @property CI_URI $uri
 * @property Firephp $firephp
 * @property ADOConnection $adodb
 * @property Content_model $content_model
 */
class Content extends MY_Controller {

  function Content()
  {
    parent::MY_Controller();
    //load model
    $this->load->model('content_model');
    //...
  }

  /**
   *
   * @return void
   * @access public
   */
  function index()
  {
    //...
  }

}
```

Using the comment like this in the controller file, the Eclipse can do autocomplete when I wrote partial code like `$this->content_model->g`. After I type `g`, I can press `Ctrl+Space` and Eclipse will show any methods in the `content_model` class.

Using eclipse is quite a burden, since it need a lot of RAM. I often must kill the firefox, since running it both will make RAM full and system started to use swap space. I know that I should add more RAM (currently I have 2x1GB), but it's not a viable solution right now.

Reading other's question and having try numerous editors and IDE in the past, I'm considering to try a free version of Komodo Edit.

My question here:

1. Can I make Komodo Edit to do autocomplete like I have currently with Eclipse PDT? Can you show me how to do it, or will Komodo Edit can use the 'pseudo property comment' that I currently have in all my Controller?
2. Do you have any other suggestion of Editor and IDE that I can use in Ubuntu and have the autocomplete for CodeIgniter?

Thank you in advance.

Update:

Right now I'm trying Komodo Edit 5.2.4 (latest version at this time). I open my existing project, and I can click the function name that will open the file where that function is defined. A cool build-in function.

When I use it for work, here is the functional I missed from PDT:

1. In Eclipse PDT, I have write a template that enable me to create a new controller and model quickly. I can code the template using `{controller_name}` and then when I use it, Eclipse allow me to replace the template code with actual text. I have tried template feature in Kodomo Edit, but it's not the same. Can you help me with Kodomo, or another IDE with similar feature?

That's all for now, I'll update more while I working using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Aptana](http://www.aptana.org/) has what you're looking for

Comment: Heads up, Apatana Studio 2 has a bug where basically no buttons work... Myself and others have noticed this in Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: yes but there is a work around. Create a Shell Script "runAptanaHack.sh" and add this is the script "#!/bin/sh
GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true /your/path/to/AptanaStudio" make it executable and run the script.

Comment: err..., aptana basically is Eclipse :) I have tried the Aptana in the past, but I more prefer the PDT over PHP edit in Aptana. Maybe I'll check the latest version, to see what's new.

Comment: I notice that in the latest version, Aptana no longer include Aptana PHP, but use PDT instead. I'm downloading right now. If Aptana could run more efficiently than Eclipse PDT, then I will use this instead.

Comment: Well, after a day using Aptana Studio 2.0.2, I will accept this answers. The RAM consumption almost the same with Eclipse PDT, but since there are jQuery support in  Aptana, it will become a plus (although I haven't use it yet). All my template is working too. Thanks Phill.

Answer (score 0):

I know only the CodeLobster have CI plugin can autocomplete .

Comment: Are they release a version for Linux?

Comment: it's doesn't support Linux , only for WIN

Answer (score 0):

i think netbeans 6.8 would be IDE of your choice, it does pseudo-property with phpdoc syntax.
i used it myself, and found no problem at code completion thing. everyone knows that netbeans take a lot of resources, but if you're efficient in using plugins/modules, it will help you nicely.

i'm using netbeans 6.8, 2gbs ram, ubuntu karmic. since i don't use few modules, i turned off subversion, cvs, team, mercurial, even the java se modules. just using php modules, web applications modules, and some basic ide features. works like a charm

**note:** make sure you're installing from the right source (netbeans.org), the one in repository does have limitations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll looking for it. I have tried in the past, but left all module as is, and not using it much.

Comment: I have download netbeans and notice the font is 'ugly', just like another java application font. Can I make it better, Eclipse used a better font, same with other gnome application. Thanks

Comment: sure there are fonts settings to pick your favorite font, so you can make the font same with another gnome applications