# Do you know an IDE with build-in jQuery and Code Igniter support?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, ide

I need an IDE that supports jQuery and Code Igniter.
Could you please provide some IDEs?

Comment: Halfway a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209126/good-javascript-ide-with-jquery-support CI works well with ZendStudio or Eclipse

Comment: 2nd half of a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099197/ide-for-codeigniter-running-in-ubuntu-linux

Answer (score 3):

I develop in CodeIgniter and jQuery with Netbeans. Does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with the [Aptana plugin](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2/download) for PHP, JavaScript, CSS, HTML.

As for jQuery specifically, I haven't tried but I think if you include jQuery library in your path you'd get hints for jQuery specific stuff, failing that you can certainly use this IDE for PHP and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on OS X there is TextMate - A great lightweight IDE with free bundles available for jQuery and CodeIgniter. A quick Google will reveal all the items.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Mac, you'll never go wrong with [Panic's Coda](http://panic.com/coda/)!

Answer (score 0):

I 2nd Coda - it has a plugin for Codeigniter syntax you can download too.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) / [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is nothing short of amazing - if you HAVE to use an IDE. I have tried all sorts before - from UE Studio, Aptana, KomodoIDE and nothing comes close. The support for git and github is the icing on the cake but it has too many great features to list here... give it a go and you won't look back

I use MooTools and it deals with that just fine but if I have ANY .js file or .php / .inc file brought into my project or referenced remotely, it parses it and does code completion and tips based upon definitions.

Further more, the actual EcmaScript natives are available and you can view their source too (ctrl+click on a symbol to navigate to source)

Downside: CodeIgniter support is marginal at the moment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-1174?projectKey=WI&query=%23Unresolved+framework+support